# Static website I am hosting cannot be reached and the server IP cannot be found

Tags: firebase, ssl, web, google-cloud-platform, web-hosting

I recently used Google Domains to register a domain and have connected it to Google Cloud Console to manage a static website. I followed the [Google Codelabs guide](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-webapp-hosting-gcs/index.html#5) to set it up and faced no issues. However, when refreshing my website, it still doesn't load and my browser (Chrome) gives me the following error message:

> **This site can’t be reached**
>
> carbonfootprint.dev’s server IP address could not be found."

As well, going to `www.carbonfootprint.dev` gives me another error message:

> **Your connection is not private**
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.carbonfootprint.dev (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).
>
> NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

...Which is confusing, because I was under the impression that a `.dev` domain suffix gives SSL certification by default.

However, in my Google Domains settings, **the website content appears as it should** in the minimized preview that exists in both the *Domain Overview* panel and *Website* panel. It has been over 48 hours, so it should have updated by now if it were just a delay issue.

For reference, [this is what my Custom resource records look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53ZmH.png), [this is what my synthetic records look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9cB7.png), and [these are my bucket details in Google Cloud Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKCGH.png). As well, [here is a preview of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4PRs.png), as shown in the Google Domains console.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `a .dev domain suffix gives SSL certification by default.` is a wrong assumption. The `.dev` domain implements HSTS which browsers recognize to force HTTPS. This has nothing to do with providing you with an SSL certificate. Your problem is that your domain name does not match the SSL certificate name.

Comment: Oh, okay. That makes sense. However, my synthetic records show that I have SSL enabled and I am unable to disable it (I've updated my post with a screenshot). Does this mean my SSL certificate is linked to my domain name? If not, how can I link the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up finding the answer thanks to @IshRaj on ServerFault.

For future reference to anyone else viewing, Google Cloud Storage **only** supports HTTP connections when hosting a static website through CNAME resource records. To serve content through a custom domain over SSL, you will need to either:

- Set up an external HTTPS load balancer ([instructions here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-https-lb-simple)),
  potentially with Google Cloud CDN ([set-up documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/setting-up-cdn-with-bucket))
- Connect a third-party Content Delivery Network to your Google Cloud
  Storage ([guide here](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/docs/how-to/cdn-interconnect))
- Host your static website on Google App Engine with Python ([guide 
  here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website))
- **Serve static website content through Google Firebase rather than

  Google Cloud Platform ([tutorial here](https://medium.com/@aleemuddin13/how-to-host-static-website-on-firebase-hosting-for-free-9de8917bebf2)/[additional support](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting))**

Personally, I went with Google Firebase (the last option), which automatically upgrades websites to https. It was simple and quick to set up and content is now directly deployable from my files. As well, with [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore/)'s automatic scalability and powerful queries, Firebase becomes a viable alternative, especially with its other features (user authentication, realtime data synchronization, machine-learning, extensions).